# How to write 4 attributes to AD users?

Tags: vbscript

The script should do this:

1. Read a CSV file: there is 5 datas in the file for each users, datas parsed with ";".  Sp 5 datas per line, ex: `aleroy;4181234567;2345678;;;`.

   You can have a line that looks like this: `aleroy;;;;;`.

   The data will only be written if there is one in the file (first one obviously does not count, because it's the AD username)
2. Like I said, it will overwrite the data in the AD if there's one in the file, otherwise, it will loop on the next user.

I'm not a programmer, so I have a lot of problem making it work.  I have corrected a few bugs, the .vbs runs correctly now, but does not write anything in my AD.

Here is the complete script I made.

```
Const FLAT_FILE_DELIMITER = ";"
Const ForReading = 1 'les modes d'ouverture possible du fichier
Const sdnDC = "DC=03QS,DC=LOCAL"'pour identifier le nom de domaine vers lequel on veut importer

Dim adoCSVConnection, adoCSVRecordSet, strPathToTextfile
'Où se trouve le fichier d'export
Dim FlatFilePath: FlatFilePath = "C:\ImportBottin.csv"
Dim strCSVFile
Dim FileSystem
Dim LigneCI
dim username, mobile, pager, telephonenumber, fax

'***************************************************************************
'On s'assure que le fichier de résultats  a bien été généré et transféré
Set FileSystem = WScript.CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")

If FileSystem.FileExists(FlatFilePath) = FALSE then
  Set FileSystem = Nothing
  WScript.quit()
End if
'***************************************************************************

' Specify CSV file name.
Set objTextFile = FileSystem.OpenTextFile(FlatFilePath, ForReading)

Set objConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
objConnection.Open "Provider=ADsDSOObject;"

'***************************************************************************

Do While objTextFile.AtEndOfStream <> true
  LigneCI = objTextFile.Readline 
  p1=Instr (LigneCI, FLAT_FILE_DELIMITER)

  if p1 > 0 then
    arr = Split(LigneCI, FLAT_FILE_DELIMITER)   

    If UBound(arr) = 4 Then
      username = arr(0)
      mobile = arr(1)
      pager = arr(2)
      telephonenumber = arr(3)
      fax = arr(4) 

      Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")  
      objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
      objCommand.CommandText = "<LDAP://"& sdnDC & _
        ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName="& _
        username &"));mobile,pager,telephonenumber,facsimileTelephoneNumber;subtree"  

      UpdateAD objCommand, mobile, pager, telephonenumber, fax
    Else
      WScript.Echo "ligne en erreur : " & csTR(LigneCI)
    End If
  end if
Loop

Sub UpdateAD (objAD,Cell,Page,Tel,Fax)
  'Permet d'envoyer le bon attribut AD à la méthode AjoutAttribut

  if not (Tel = "" or Tel = "NULL") then
    AjoutAttribut objAD,"telephonenumber", Tel
  end if

  if not (Cell = "" or Cell = "NULL")   then
    AjoutAttribut objAD,"mobile",Cell
  end if

  if not (Page = "" or Page = "NULL")   then
    AjoutAttribut objAD,"pager",Page
  end if

  if not (Fax = "" or Fax = "NULL")then
    AjoutAttribut objAD,"facsimileTelephoneNumber",Fax
  end if
end sub

Sub AjoutAttribut (Obj,nomAttribut,Attribut)
  'Méthode qui ajoute une valeur d'attribut à un objet de l'AD
  On Error Resume Next
  Err.Number=0
  AttributAct=Obj.get(nomAttribut)

  if strComp(Attribut,AttributAct,1)<>0 and Attribut <> "" and Attribut <> "NULL" then
    Obj.Put nomAttribut,Attribut
  end if

  if Attribut <> "" and not isnull(Attribut) then
    Obj.Put nomAttribut,Attribut
  end if
end sub
```

Answer (score 0):

You're passing the ADO Command object to your subroutines and then try to call `Get` and `Put` on it. That doesn't work (you don't see the error, though, because you suppress it with `On Error Resume Next`).

You need to `Execute` the AD query to actually retrieve the users/properties, and then iterate over the returned list:

```
Set objCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")
objCommand.ActiveConnection = objConnection
objCommand.CommandText = "<LDAP://"& sdnDC & _
  ">;(&(objectCategory=person)(objectClass=user)(userPrincipalName="& _
  username &"));mobile,pager,telephonenumber,facsimileTelephoneNumber;subtree"

Set rs = objCommand.Execute
Do Until rs.EOF
  UpdateAD rs, mobile, pager, telephonenumber, fax
  rs.MoveNext
Loop
```

I don't think you can update user properties via the recordset. For updating properties you need to get the user objects via their distinguished names. You also need to call `SetInfo` to actually write the updated information back to the AD:

```
Set user = GetObject("LDAP://" & rs.Fields("distinguishedName").Value)
user.Put "mobile", "555-1234"
user.SetInfo
```

You may want to take a look at ActiveXperts [scripts for managing AD users](http://www.activexperts.com/activmonitor/windowsmanagement/adminscripts/usersgroups/users/). They will help you get an idea of how these things work.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I'll take a deeper look this weekend. I'll keep you informed

And, thank'S again. Very much appreciated